# What are the desired questions that should to be in SM (stackexchangemath)?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, soft-question

According to many questions posted in SM, I see that SM gives high importance for the related questions to Real analysis and number theory and contests  where "MO" gives high importance to Algebra and geometry.

At this point I would be interested to know for which interests and desired questions SM was created and what are the important problems that should be posted in order to be considered by  community.

Comment: You can google for what's on topic on math.stackexchange.

Comment: in the general for google ,may i will across a spam info, but it was good if I know the answer from SM

Comment: I reformatted the question. Please note that line breaks are automatic. You don't need to start a new line, unless you want to begin a new paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on the posts that are appropriate on Math.Stackexchange. The distinction between this site and MathOverflow is that MO is meant for research level mathematics.

Comment: ok, thank you .If MO of research level what about SM ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik, on Math.SE we have many different levels of mathematics. We have recreational mathematicians ask questions that are just interesting. Many users are students who are having trouble with a particular concept in their homework.

Comment: nice , i cited those in my question , but i seek for interest questions